# Regex for matching substring in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to C#
I was trying regex to match following substring from the actual string which contains alpha numeric words and hyperlinks as well.

substring : "your policy may provide coverage with the Rideshare Coverage"

actual string:
"If you drive for a ridesharing company like Uber or Lyft, your policy may provide coverage with the Rideshare Coverage endorsement. This endorsement extends your insurance coverage when you are logged into a ridesharing app and awaiting a match [1]. However, please note that the endorsement does not cover you while you are en route to pick up a passenger or while you have a passenger in the car [1]. It's important to review your policy and contact your insurance provider for specific details and coverage options [2].\r\n\r\n[1]: https://www.farmersdirect.com/faq "Farmers Insurance"\r\n[2]: https://www.farmersdirect.com/get-a-quote/ "Farmers Insurance""

Tried with:
new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*your policy may provide coverage with the Rideshare Coverage [a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

But failed
Assert.Matches() Failure: Pattern not found in value
Regex: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*your policy may provide coverage with"···
Value: "If you drive for a ridesharing company like Uber o"···

Could you please help to build correct regex?
Thanks

Comment: use Expresso Regular Expression Tool - it is best for testing regexes

Comment: Your regex may be also sumple @"your policy may provide coverage with the Rideshare Coverage" if thats is what You are loking for with no magical changes in this part?

Comment: Your regular expression is attempting to match the start of the string, a single alphanumeric character, then the search term, a single space, a single alphanumeric character and then the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that a regular expression is the best solution for what you're attempting to do. Why not use [`String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0)

```cs
var index = actualString.IndexOf(subString);
```

If the substring is found then index will be greater than -1.